# How to sum multiple values from firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

class _RecordState extends State {

String _customerName,_totalAmount,_currentPaid,_totalDue;
Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Customers Details')
),
body: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: [
SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,),
Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
child: WavyAnimatedTextKit(
textStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize: 32.0,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
color: Colors.black),
text: ['ADD CUSTOMERS'],
isRepeatingAnimation: true,
speed: Duration(milliseconds: 150),),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
child: TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
labelText: "Customer Name",
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
borderSide:
BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey)),
),
onChanged: (input){
setState(() {
_customerName = input;
});
},
),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
child: TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
labelText: "Total Amount",
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
borderSide:
BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey)),
),
onChanged: (input){
setState(() {
//_totalAmount = input;
_totalAmount = input;
});
},
),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
child: TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
labelText: "Current Paid",
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
borderSide:
BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey)),
),
onChanged: (input){
setState(() {
_currentPaid = input;
});
},
),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
child: TextFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
labelText: "Total Due",
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
borderSide:
BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey)),
),
onChanged: (input){
setState(() {
_totalDue = input;
});
},
),
),
FlatButton(
color: Colors.red,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
),
onPressed: (){
setState(() {
firestore.collection('items').add({
'Customer_Name': _customerName,
'Total_Amount': int.parse(this._totalAmount),
'Current_Paid': int.parse(this._currentPaid),
'Total_Due': int.parse(this._totalDue)
});
});
},
child: Text('Add')),
Text('$Add'),
],
),
),
);
}
}
**I want to sum of Total amount. But I couldn't found the solution, please if anyone can give me the solution**

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. **Please format your code** and check the preview of your post before posting, create a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this because it is very hard for us to dig through this large chunk of code to find the problem. Also try elaborate to more and give more explanation about your code

Answer (score 0):

This is how to calculate it:

```
int totalSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   totalSum += i;
}

print(totalSum);
```